# Can't delete files from Trash

Tags: terminal, finder, trash

I'm trying to empty my trash, and it seems that I having some problem with encoding:

```
MacKassner:501 kassner$ rm -Rf t/t/
rm: t/t//t: Directory not empty
rm: t/t/: Directory not empty
```

Ok then, let's see what's inside:

```
MacKassner:t kassner$ pwd
/Volumes/DATA/.Trashes/501/t/t/t
MacKassner:t kassner$ ls -la
ls: 07 The Kids (feat. Janelle Monáe).mp3: No such file or directory
total 128
drwxrwxrwx  1 kassner  staff  32768 Jan  7 10:42 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 kassner  staff  32768 Feb  4 18:12 ..
```

It seems a problem with the special char on that file. I can't empty trash using Finder either (even securely).

EDIT: StackExchange changes a litte bit the exhibition of the special character. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you hold option and command and then use the mouse to empty trash does that help?

Comment: @bmike Not really. Shift neither.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to trash a folder is to move another folder with the same name into the existing folder. It looks like you have a folder `t` which might be amenable to making a new folder on the data drive and name it identically to the folder you wish to nuke and then trashing the "new" `t` folder.

If that doesn't work, you should be able to open a finder window and attempt to rename the problematic file. See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201583 for details.

Lastly, if nothing works, consider posting what format the /Volumes/DATA is via `diskutil list` and `sudo ls -laOR /Volumes/DATA/.Trashes/`

Comment: none of that explained on the link worked. Trashing a new folder with the same name, OSX appends the time to the folder name when on Trash. I guess the only solution is to format the disk.

Answer (score 0):

On a terminal window, try the following:

```
find /Volumes/DATA/.Trashes/501/t/t/t -type f -exec rm -f {} ';'
```

Comment: Thanks @jherran, but I got the same: `find: /Volumes/DATA/.Trashes/501/t/t/t/07 The Kids (feat. Janelle Monáe).mp3: No such file or directory
`